# Plpython3u with PostgreSQL:Connection to the server has been lost

Tags: python, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL Server 12.2 with python 3.7.
PostgreSQL create extension plpython3u, but appear the next error when create the function:

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pymax (a integer, b integer)
  RETURNS integer
AS $$
  if (a is None) or (b is None):
    return None
  if a > b:
    return a
  return b
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Messages:
Connection to the server has been lost.

The application has lost the database connection:
⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
⁃ The user session may have timed out.
Do you want to continue and establish a new session?

Thanks

Comment: Look in the database server log file to see what message it reported.  What OS are you using?  How did you install PostgreSQL and the extensions?